# The Rotation Axes are Messed Up!

Tags: rigging, bezier-curves

I'm in a hurry because I have a client waiting on me for this project, but I've run into an issue with rigging my character.  By the way, instead of attaching the curve controls to the joints, I've attached them to the objects of the character because there are no joints.  Why?  Because the character is a robot and doesn't need any weight-paints.  Anyways, so for some reason, when I rotate certain curves that control parts of the body, the object doesn't rotate on that axis.  I will provide 2 examples, please read them both to get a good understanding of my problem.

Example 1: The thumb.  When I rotate the base thumb curve control on the Z axis (in global mode), it rotates the object on the X axis instead.  Not to mention that when I use local mode (which because the thumb has been turned 45 degrees as a thumb should be and obviously I applied the transforms to delta to clear them), and when I rotate the thumb on the Y axis it rotates I think on the Z axis.

Example 2: The right hand.  The right hand was duplicated from the left hand but I applied the transforms to delta to clear their transforms... and I did the same thing with the curve that controls that hand.  So I don't see why there would be any issues with the rotation but yet, there is.  When I try to rotate the right hand's curve control on the Y axis (in global mode), although it rotates on the Y axis, it rotates in the opposite direction that I'm moving my mouse to rotate the curve.  So, when I rotate the curve control clockwise (when looking at the front of the character), the curve rotates counterclockwise.

So, I would like to fix this issue so that the objects rotate on the correct axes and also could someone show me how to make a custom rotation axis?  What if, for example, an object is turned a certain way and is suppose to only rotate on the Y in a very specific direction but the global and local modes don't provide that axis as the direction I'd like to rotate the object, how do I create a custom axis to match the direction I want to rotate the object so I don't have to grab the middle to rotate it (which can be difficult)?

So, 2 things.. how to fix my issue and how to create custom rotation axes.

I really need to know as soon as possible so any help is very much appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not experienced with rigging, but do your bones have the correct axis?  (meaning that when you display the axis of the bones, are they oriented correctly)

Comment: Millard, remember, I said I did not use joints (aka bones). I parented the curves directly to the objects because it's a robot and there's no need for weight-paints with my particular robot model.

Comment: please show some screenshots, it's very hard to understand without any, also, I don't know how you use curve control, why don't you use bones? It would simplify your animations a lot